# Hapi.js upload file to S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hapi.js

I'm in trouble with uploading file to Amazon S3 using node.js (hapi). Here's the code of my route:

```
{
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/upload',
        config: {
            auth: {
                mode: 'optional',
            },
            payload:{
                maxBytes: 209715200,
                output:'stream',
                parse: true
            }, 
            handler: function(request, reply) {

                var filePath = path.join(__dirname, request.payload.file.hapi.filename);

                fs.readFile(filePath, function(err, data) {

                    console.log(data);

                    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
                    s3.putObject({
                        Bucket: 'mybucket',
                        Key: request.payload.file.hapi.filename,
                        Body: data,
                        ACL: 'public-read'
                    }, function (err) {
                        if (err) { throw err; }
                    });

                });

                reply(request.payload.file);

            }
        }
    }
```

What's wrong? My files uploads to the S3 cluster, but with 0 bytes size. What did I do wrong? Console.log for data returns `<Buffer >`

I don't know why. Can someone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: what is the error while you are uploading the file?

Comment: There's no error. My files just uploads with 0 bytes size

Comment: try writing 'reply(request.payload.file);' in 's3.putObject' function